# Weak derivative under integral sign

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, derivatives, sobolev-spaces

Consider a locally integrable function $u$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (in $C^\infty$, for argument's sake). Then the function $f:[0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by
\begin{equation}
f(r,x) = \int_{B_r(x)} u(y)\,dy = \int_{B_r(0)} u(x+y)\,dy
\end{equation}
is well-defined, with
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(r,x) = \int_{B_r(0)}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}(x+y)\,dy = \int_{B_r(x)} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}(y)\,dy = \int_{\partial B_r(x)} u(z)\nu^i(z)\,dS(z),
\end{equation}
by differentiation under the integral sign followed by the divergence theorem. Here, $\nu^i(z)$ is the $i$'th component of the outward pointing normal vector at $z\in\partial B_r(x)$.

I am interested in obtaining an analogue for $(1)$ for a function $u\in W_{\mathrm{loc}}^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, meaning $u$ and its weak first derivatives belong to $L^p(K)$ for any compact $K\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. Of course, the final equality in $(1)$ cannot be obtained without further regularity assumptions on $u$, but do we still have the identity
\begin{equation} 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(r,x)= \int_{B_r(x)} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}(y)\,dy,
\end{equation}
with weak derivatives? I don't believe the 'Measure Theory Statement' of [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) applies, since the second point only holds a.e. A reference to a book addressing this sort of stuff would also be welcome. Thank you!

Comment: Did you try just using the definition of weak derivatives?

Comment: @LL3.14 That is indeed what I tried first, in an attempt to shift the problem onto smooth test functions. But I couldn't get anything useful from this, could you please expand?